# OpenGL rendering and rasterization of slivers

Tags: opengl, rendering

I am testing some rendering stuff with OpenGL and I noticed that I have some issues with long thin polygons that are forming a plane. So when having two of these long polygons directly next to each other, snapping at the long side, I noticed that some of the pixels at the edge are invisible. These invisible pixels move around when I move the camera.

What I found is that this is because the pixels at the edge of these "sliver" polygons will be invisible because the rasterization thinks that they are not within that polygon at this specific view angle.

What I didn't figure out is how to tell OpenGL to also put pixels on screen that are directly at the edge of that polygon.

If you found my description of the problem a bit weird see http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs314/Vjan2008/slides/week5.day3-4x4.pdf page 27 and following. That's what I mean.

EDIT: ok i think i have to make clear what my problem is, because i have a feeling that i cant adress it with anti aliasing techniques

```
aaa|b|cc
aaa|b|cc
aaa|b|cc
   ^ ^
   1 2

- the polygons a, b and c form a plane
- some pixels at edge 1 and 2 are invisible at certain camera angles
```

Comment: Normally these artifacts can be reduced by enabling oversampling. Not a solution just a hint.

Comment: do you mean "anti-aliasing" with oversampling? e.g. with GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH?

Comment: @cdx: Most likely FSAA i.e. multisampling was meant.

Comment: Are the vertices shared between your a, b, c polygons ?

Comment: a b and c are in that case quads, but edgeflag is set to 0 for vertices of edge 1 and 2

Comment: ... ok i think i get it: in my case i have 12 vertices, but i should have 8, so the vertices should be shared between the polygons to avoid the problems i have

Answer (score 1):

> What I didn't figure out is how to tell OpenGL to also put pixels on screen that are directly at the edge of that polygon.

In general, you don't. If OpenGL thinks that a part of a triangle is too thin to be rendered for a given resolution, then it's too thin to be rendered. The general form of this issue is called called "aliasing".

The solution is to use an antialiasing technique. For example, multisampling. When you create the context, select a number of samples to use.